# C++ Tic Tac Toe AI Woes... Not MINMAX

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I have been attempting to make a simple Tic Tac Toe AI program with two separate "modes". One in which the user will play the computer which will choose a purely random number and another in which the computer's choice will be somewhat educated.

I am having trouble implementing this AI part to the program... I can get it to work fine with just the random tile selection. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const char userMark = 'X';
const char computerMark = 'O';

enum gameStatus { gameOnGoing, gameFinished, userWins, computerWins };

class tictactoe {

private:
    char square[9] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8' };
    unsigned int delay_ms = 100;

public:
    bool active = true;
    void DrawBoard(void);
    bool updateBoard(int choice, char playerMark);
    int generateComputerChoice(void);
    gameStatus checkGame(void);
    bool checkforWinningLines(char playerMark);
    int numberOfAvailableSpaces(void);
    void delay(void);

    //bool checkforPitfalls(char playerMark);

};

int main()
{
    tictactoe game;
    int choice = 0;
    char smartAI;
        cout << "Would you like to play on 'hard mode'? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> smartAI;

    game.DrawBoard();

    while (game.active) {
        cout << "Please enter your available move :";
        cin >> choice;
        if (game.updateBoard(choice, userMark))
        {
            game.DrawBoard();
            game.delay();

            int computerChoice = game.generateComputerChoice();
            game.updateBoard(computerChoice, computerMark);
            game.DrawBoard();

            switch (game.checkGame()) {
            case gameOnGoing:
                // We just need to around again - game still on
                break;
            case gameFinished:
                cout << "Game is over: No winner" << endl;
                game.active = false;
                break;
            case userWins:
                cout << "User wins" << endl;
                game.active = false;
                break;
            case computerWins:
                cout << "Computer wins" << endl;
                game.active = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: Please select another space" << endl;
            // go around again
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool tictactoe::checkforWinningLines(char playerMark)
{
    // Horizontal
    if ((square[0] == playerMark &&square[1] == playerMark && square[2] == playerMark) ||
        (square[3] == playerMark &&square[4] == playerMark && square[5] == playerMark) ||
        (square[6] == playerMark &&square[7] == playerMark && square[8] == playerMark) ||
        (square[0] == playerMark &&square[3] == playerMark && square[6] == playerMark) ||
        (square[1] == playerMark &&square[4] == playerMark && square[7] == playerMark) ||
        (square[2] == playerMark &&square[5] == playerMark && square[8] == playerMark) ||
        (square[0] == playerMark &&square[4] == playerMark && square[8] == playerMark) ||
        (square[2] == playerMark &&square[4] == playerMark && square[6] == playerMark))

    {
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
void tictactoe::DrawBoard()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << square[0] << "  |  " << square[1] << "  |  " << square[2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << square[3] << "  |  " << square[4] << "  |  " << square[5] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << square[6] << "  |  " << square[7] << "  |  " << square[8] << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl << endl;
}

void tictactoe::delay()
{
    //Introduces a delay.
    //sleep(delay_ms);
}

bool tictactoe::updateBoard(int choice, char playerMark)
{
    bool updated = false;
    if (choice < 9 && choice >= 0)
    {
        if (square[choice] != userMark &&
            square[choice] != computerMark)
        {
            square[choice] = playerMark;
            updated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Already chosen - Pick another
            updated = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid number - not in range.
        updated = false;
    }

    return updated;
}

gameStatus tictactoe::checkGame(void)
{
    gameStatus status;

    if (checkforWinningLines(computerMark))
    {
        status = computerWins;
    }
    else if (checkforWinningLines(userMark))
    {
        status = userWins;

    }
    else    if (numberOfAvailableSpaces() > 0)
    {
        status = gameOnGoing;
    }
    else
    {
        status = gameFinished;
    }

    return status;
}

int tictactoe::numberOfAvailableSpaces(void)
{
    int count = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (square[i] == userMark ||
            square[i] == computerMark)
        {
            count--;                     //count-- = count -1
        }
    }
    return count;
}


    int tictactoe::generateComputerChoice(void)
{
    if (smartAI == 'N' || 'n')
    {
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    unsigned int choice;

        do {
            choice = rand() % 8;

        } while ((square[choice] == userMark ||
            square[choice] == computerMark) && numberOfAvailableSpaces() >= 0);
        return choice;
    }
    else if (smartAI == 'Y' || 'y')
    {
        do {
            if (square[0] == square[1] == userMark || square[5] == square[8] == userMark || square[4] == square[6] == userMark)
            {
                square[2] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[1] == sqaure[2] == userMark || square[3] == square[6] == userMark || square[4] == square[8] == userMark)
            {
                square[0] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[0] == sqaure[2] == userMark || square[4] == square[7] == userMark)
            {
                square[1] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[3] == sqaure[4] == userMark || square[2] == square[8] == userMark)
            {
                square[5] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[4] == sqaure[5] == userMark || square[0] == square[6] == userMark)
            {
                square[3] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[3] == sqaure[5] == userMark || square[1] == square[7] == userMark || square[0] == square[8] == userMark || square[6] == square[2] == userMark)
            {
                square[4] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[6] == sqaure[7] == userMark || square[2] == square[5] == userMark || square[0] == square[4] == userMark)
            {
                square[8] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[7] == sqaure[8] == userMark || square[0] == square[3] == userMark || square[2] == square[4] == userMark)
            {
                square[6] = choice;
            }
            else if (square[6] == sqaure[8] == userMark || square[1] == square[4] == userMark)
            {
                square[7] = choice;
            }
            while ((square[choice] == userMark ||
                square[choice] == computerMark) && numberOfAvailableSpaces() >= 0);
            return choice;
        }
    }

}


//bool tictactoe::checkforPitfalls(char playermark)
/*
                                                 {
                                                 if (square[4] == computerMark && ((square[0] == userMark && square[8] == userMark ) || (square[2] == userMark && square[6] == userMark)) && (square[1]==0 && square[3]==0  && square[5]==0 && square[7]==0))
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[8] == userMark && square[2] == userMark && square[3] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[6] == userMark && square[0] == userMark && square[5] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[6] == userMark && square[1] == userMark && square[8] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[8] == userMark && square[1] == userMark && square[6] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[8] == userMark && square[1] == userMark && square[3] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else if (square[4] == computerMark && square[0] == userMark && square[6] == computerMark && square[7] == computerMark && square[1] == userMark && square[2] == userMark && square[3] == userMark && square[8] == userMark)
                                                 return true;
                                                 else
                                                 return false;
                                                 }*/
```

Comment: You're going to have to define what "having trouble" means. SO is not a code writing service. What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Apologies, I totally understand that SO is not for having someone write your code for you... I have been having issues with the generateCoomputerChoice function. I am unable to get this to work in that the 'smartAI' variable is saying it is undefined and also 'choice' is saying the same within the second if statement. I am asking for pointers or suggestions as opposed to someone providing the answer

Comment: `smartAI` is defined in the scope of `main`, which your `generateComputerChoice` can't access. You need to make `smartAI` globally accessible somehow or pass the value to `generateComputerChoice`.

Answer (score 0):

AI is basically an agent that can be categorized in several types, you can implement and create a simple reflex agent that basis its move on the best current marker it can place or it can use a utility based agent whose goal is to win with min moves, or stopping using from reaching its goal state.

You must use some kind of a searching agent that uses BFS/DFS/Heuristic etc to check what could be your agents best possible move. For increasing your AI's difficulty you can check provide it with a tree data structure that can search for future moves according to how the game can carry out.

A possible code could be (its copied but provides a basic example of how AI works).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char matrix[3][3];  //intitial matrix declaration

char check(void); // declaration of functions
void init_matrix(void);
void get_player_move(void);
void get_computer_move(void);
void disp_matrix(void);

int main(void)
{
  char done;

  cout<<"Human vs. AI Tic Tac Toe."<<endl;
  cout<<"You will be playing against the computer as 'X'"<<endl;

  done =  ' ';
  init_matrix();

  do {
    disp_matrix();
    get_player_move();
    done = check(); /* check winner */
    if(done!= ' ') break; /* if winner found...*/
    get_computer_move();
    done = check(); /* check for winner again */
  } while(done== ' ');

  if(done=='X')
  cout<<"Human won! (but AI very dumb anyway)\n";
  else
  cout<<"AI so stupid still can win against you..."<<endl;
  disp_matrix(); /* show final positions */

  return 0;
}

/*Functions and function prototypes below
==============================================================================*/

void init_matrix(void) //matrix intitialisation
{
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    for(j=0; j<3; j++) matrix[i][j] =  ' ';
}


void get_player_move(void) //call function for player input
{
  int x, y;

  cout<<"Enter X,Y coordinates for your move: ";
  scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);

  x--; y--;

  if(matrix[x][y]!= ' '){
    cout<<"Invalid move, try again.\n";
    get_player_move();
  }
  else matrix[x][y] = 'X';
}

void get_computer_move(void) //AI move input
{
  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
      if(matrix[i][j]==' ') break;
    if(matrix[i][j]==' ') break;
  }

  if(i*j==9)  {
    cout<<"draw\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  else
    matrix[i][j] = 'O';
}

void disp_matrix(void) //matrix display
{
  int t;

  for(t=0; t<3; t++)
{
    printf(" %c | %c | %c ",matrix[t][0],
            matrix[t][1], matrix [t][2]);
    if(t!=2)
    printf("\n---|---|---\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}


char check(void) //used for identifying winner
{
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check rows */
    if(matrix[i][0]==matrix[i][1] &&
       matrix[i][0]==matrix[i][2]) return matrix[i][0];

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check columns */
    if(matrix[0][i]==matrix[1][i] &&
       matrix[0][i]==matrix[2][i]) return matrix[0][i];

  /* test diagonals */
  if(matrix[0][0]==matrix[1][1] &&
     matrix[1][1]==matrix[2][2])
       return matrix[0][0];

  if(matrix[0][2]==matrix[1][1] &&
     matrix[1][1]==matrix[2][0])
       return matrix[0][2];

  return ' ';
}
```

Comment: If `j` is 3 when executing the second `if(matrix[i][j]==' ') break;` line in `get_computer_move()`, its index is out of bounds, and when `i` is 2 here, this will access memory beyond the array's allocation (this case ends up testing as the "draw" condition, where both `i` and `j` are 3 after the outermost loop ends).  This line only exists as a way to allow the inner `break` to break out of both loops, so it could safely be replaced with `if(j < 3) break;`